# SQL NTILE function arithmetic overflow error

Tags: sql-server

The following statement works as expected:

```
SELECT SaleId, NTILE(16) 
  OVER (ORDER BY SaleId) AS Chunk
  FROM EPR_SaleHeader
```

Change the `NTILE` call to use a parameter:

```
DECLARE @Slices int = 16
 SELECT SaleId, NTILE(@Slices) 
   OVER ( ORDER BY SaleId) AS Chunk
   FROM EPR_SaleHeader
```

and the result is an arithmetic overflow error.

`SaleId` is an int field in a table of approximately 750,000 rows.

Does anyone have an explanation for the error?

Comment: `NTILE` by itself isn't generating the error, must be another thing. Make sure to post the exact query you are using.

Comment: Does `EPR_SaleHeader` have any calculated fields that might cause an overflow when evaluated, for any row? Aside from `NTILE` being nondeterministic, `NTILE(16)` and `NTILE(@Slices)` will probably have different execution plans, causing different rows to be evaluated. Do things change when you add `WITH (RECOMPILE)` to the query using a parameter?

Comment: Please post entire real query and table structure

Comment: @FDavidov: the docs are wrong, or possibly just out of date. Arbitrary expressions (including variables and computations) are supported there since at least SQL Server 2012, and the examples even include one using a variable. The only real restriction is that the expression cannot refer to columns of the table being selected, which is "constant within the context of the operation", which may be what the writer was thinking of (but that does not excuse the wording).

Comment: @JeroenMostert you could be right. Just checked again the page and its applicability is for SQL Server 2008. I'm deleting my previous comment. Thanks for the correction!!

Comment: @DhruvJoshi the error message is "Arithmetic overflow occurred."

Comment: @EzLo, the two lines are the full query.

Comment: @FDavidov: the page is actually supposed to apply to all versions from SQL Server 2008 onwards, and any restrictions in previous versions should be mentioned. I've submitted a correction to simply remove the "constant" part.

Comment: You can edit your original question to supply details; code in comments is unnecessarily hard to read. The fact that the table is a clustered columnstore is probably relevant (this might be a bug in batch processing mode). Include your SQL Server version. Also, try varying the value used for `NTILE`, and playing with the `MAXDOP` option.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, cool!!